# Помогите с redirect в .htaccess

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

```
redirect /index.php?categoryID=647 http://other_site.ru/
```

Т.е. именно с этой категории магазина отсылка на другой сайт. Не работает. Подозреваю, что проблема из-за аргумента. Как сделать правильно?

**Обновление**

В аналогичном, но англоязычном месте, на час позже был предложен несколько видоизмененный вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categoryID=647$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://other_site.ru? [R,L]
```

Если бы вы прокомментировали разницу, было бы супер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не работает, потому что mod_rewrite по-умолчанию разбирает адреса без параметров.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewiteRule index.php?categoryid=647 http://your-website.ru [R]
```

**Обновление:**
А так работает:

```
#ищем необходимый параметр и его значение
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} categoryid=647 [NC]
#делаем редирект, если найден параметр из предыдущей строки 
RewriteRule .* http://your-website.ru? [R,L]
```

**Обновление 2**

А что комментировать?

В этом варианте четко определяется, что именно `/index.php?categoryid=647` будет перенаправлен на `http://other_site.ru`. В моем варианте все страницы (`/about.php?categoryid=647 или /wtf.php?categoryid=647`) будут перенаправлены на `http://your-website.ru`

============================

Хотя правильнее было бы делать так:

```
\#определяем страницу, к которой будет вызов с параметром categoryid
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about.php [NC] 
\#определяем значение параметра
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} categoryid=647 [NC]
\#делаем редирект
RewriteRule http://your-website.ru? [R,L]
```

Да, и еще `categoryid` у них обязательно должен идти первым параметром. Т.е. `/index.php?param=true&categoryid=647` не сработает. И у меня еще регистронезависимость во всех строчках и параметрах стоит. ))

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, так работает. Спасибо!